# Partitioning a normal RDD in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, partitioning

I am aware that for a PairRDD (key, value), we can give our own partitioning scheme or partition it by using the default partitioners (hash and range). But, is there a way to partition a normal RDD by using our own partition class ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Need to inherit abstract class `org.apache.spark.Partitioner` and provide an implementation for two methods:

```
class WeekDayPartitioner extends Partitioner {
  override def numPartitions: Int = 7
  override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = key.asInstanceOf[LocalDate].getDayOfWeek
}

val partitioner = new WeekDayPartitioner()
myRdd.partitionBy(partitioner) //RDD[(LocalDate, String)]
```

Comment: Hi @falcon-le0, thanks for your time looking into my question. I actually researched by best and the I am unable to locate the partitionBy method on a plain rdd. This method is available only in pairRDD object. can you please let me know if it available by any other ways. Thanks!